# Can I mine with both AMD gpu and AMD integrated graphics at the same time

Tags: mining-hardware, mining-theory, miner-configuration

Right off the bat I'm not planning to mine bitcoins but i would like to have this knowledge for some other cryptocurrency. I have an old pc with AMD A8 cpu that has integrated graphics and AMD Radeon HD 7890. I want to know is it possible for me two mine with both integrated and dedicated card at the same time.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Im running an A-10 and a gtx260 and i can use both to mine seperate/combined coins, shouldnt be any different for you? :)